# mysqlimport gives error when run as cron job but not interactively (Ubuntu 14.02)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, mysql, crontab

I have a bash script which downloads and then imports a CSV file into a local MySQL.  The database is MySQL 5.6 on Ubuntu 14.04, I'm loading data with the following statement (bash):

```
 mysqlimport --ignore-lines=1 --lines-terminated-by='\n' --fields-terminated-by=',' --verbose --local --user=xx --password=xxxxxxxx mydb /var/www/mysite/data/daily_info.csv
```

the problem is that when I launch the script from the command line, with the same user, it runs fine from download through the import phase.
I added a crontab entry to run the script with the command

```
crontab -u theuser -e
```

The user **'theuser'** is the same that launches correctly the script from the command line.  'daily_info' is also the name of the table to which data is added by the **mysqlimport** command.

I'd expect that the crontab task would run as **'theuser'** allowing access to all the folders and file, *just as the interactive shell does*, but this seems not true. The scheduled job gives me the this error message

```
mysqlimport: Error: 1290, The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement, when using table: daily_info
```

I've found many questions related to the **secure-file-priv** issue but the answers don't fit well with this case, I suspect that the command in my script (mysqlimport) is running with a different user, but I can't diagnose it.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an explanation but arrived to a (partial) solution to my own question. I hope others may contribute to enhance this.
When run from the command line the script runs ok, when it's activated from crontab it applies what's set in the **secure_file_priv** mysql variable.
So I modified the **my.cnf** file adding a line under the **[mysqld]** group as shown here:

```
[mysqld]
...other settings here...
secure-file-priv=/mypath/datafolder/
```

After that you must restart mysql and check if the change takes effect with this query:

```
mysql> show variables like 'secure-file-priv';
+------------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value                  |
+------------------+------------------------+
| secure_file_priv | /mypath/datafolder/    |
+------------------+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Notice that when the db loads the **.cnf** file the '-' character is converted into '_' (underscore).